# How to troubleshoot scala3 program compilation error on Windows 7

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I have installed the scala compiler and repl on my Windows 7 PC:

```
bitsadmin /transfer cs-cli https://git.io/coursier-cli-windows-exe "%cd%\cs.exe"
cs install scala3-compiler
cs install scala3-repl
```

I then copied a hello world program from this link:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/taste-hello-world.html

I then try to compile with scalac:

```
D:\projects\Coursera\scala\code\play>scalac Hello.scala
SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)
At line:29 char:10
+     throw <<<<  "SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)"
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (SetConsoleMode ...din a console?):String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)

Hello.scala:1: error: expected start of definition
@main def hello = println("Hello, world!")
  ^
1 error

D:\projects\Coursera\scala\code\play>
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I build this program?

I am running Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

Updated info:

```
D:\projects\Coursera\scala\code\play>scalac -version
SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)
At line:29 char:10
+     throw <<<<  "SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)"
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (SetConsoleMode ...din a console?):String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)

Scala compiler version 2.13.6 -- Copyright 2002-2021, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.

D:\projects\Coursera\scala\code\play>scala3-compiler Hello.scala
SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)
At line:29 char:10
+     throw <<<<  "SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)"
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (SetConsoleMode ...din a console?):String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)

D:\projects\Coursera\scala\code\play>dir
 Volume in drive D is DATAPART1
 Volume Serial Number is A23F-1A44

 Directory of D:\projects\Coursera\scala\code\play

25/06/2021  21:55    <DIR>          .
25/06/2021  21:55    <DIR>          ..
25/06/2021  21:55               758 Hello$package$.class
25/06/2021  21:55               267 Hello$package.class
25/06/2021  21:55               567 Hello$package.tasty
25/06/2021  21:55               912 hello.class
25/06/2021  17:18                44 Hello.scala
25/06/2021  21:55               474 hello.tasty
               6 File(s)          3,022 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  522,054,057,984 bytes free

D:\projects\Coursera\scala\code\play>scala hello
SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)
At line:29 char:10
+     throw <<<<  "SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)"
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (SetConsoleMode ...din a console?):String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
scala/util/CommandLineParser$ParseError
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.RichClassLoader$.$anonfun$tryClass$extension$1(ScalaClassLoader.scala:47)
        at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.$anonfun$opt$1(Exception.scala:245)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:227)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.opt(Exception.scala:245)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.RichClassLoader$.tryClass$extension(ScalaClassLoader.scala:47)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.RichClassLoader$.run$extension(ScalaClassLoader.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run(ObjectRunner.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run$(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:45)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch$(ObjectRunner.scala:36)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:70)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:91)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:108)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at coursier.bootstrap.launcher.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at coursier.bootstrap.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
scala.util.CommandLineParser$ParseError
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 24 more

D:\projects\Coursera\scala\code\play>
```

Tried to run as scala3-compiler hello

```
D:\projects\Coursera\scala\code\play>scala3-compiler hello
SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)
At line:29 char:10
+     throw <<<<  "SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)"
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (SetConsoleMode ...din a console?):String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetConsoleMode failed (is stdin a console?)

not found: hello
1 error found
```

Comment: Are you sure `scalac` there is the **Scala 3** compiler? Try calling `scalac -version` to confirm, I would guess it is actually the **Scala 2** compiler and that for using the **Scala 3** one you should do `scala3-compiler Hello.scala`

Comment: So it seems using the `scala3-compiler` command worked, now I believe the way of running the code would also be `scala3-compiler Hello`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Not sure, because I don't seem to be able to run the program - see above.

Comment: Again you are using the `2.13` compiler to run a **Scala 3** program, try with `scala3-compiler Hello` to run it.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - tried that - see above. - also tried scala3-compiler Hello - same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala3-compiler hello.scala
scala3 Hello
```

or
as example from scala-lang contains annotation @main
so

```
def hello (hello is the class in the compiler output)
```

so the command to run it:

```
scala3 hello
```

The program will run nevertheless errors in cmd

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).